# Expect script can't spawn dhclient command

Tags: ubuntu, tcl, expect

I'm writing a tcl expect script to connect to a vpn server (softether) on an Ubuntu client. The client connects to the vpn server ok then I want to run "dhclient vpn_tun0" to get an IP address from the vpn server, where vpn_tun0 is the name of my adapter. Running the command in terminal works fine but I can't figure out how to make it work in the script.

I have tried the following but no luck. I have also googled the problem extensively.

```
spawn dhclient vpn_tun0 

spawn "dhclient vpn_tun0"

send "dhclient vpn_tun0"
```

The first command results in no error but no IP.

The second results in

```
spawn dhclient vpn_tun0
couldn't execute "dhclient vpn_tun0": no such file or directory
    while executing
"spawn "dhclient vpn_tun0""
```

The third just sends the text to the terminal output.

Here is a test script after the vpn is connected:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if { [exec id -u] ne 0 } {
   puts "sorry. you are not root"
   exit 1
}

spawn dhclient vpn_tun0

close
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: I edited to question to answer your question

Comment: When you run dhclient from your shell prompt, do you need to interact with it? If no, then you don't need to spawn it from expect, `exec dhclient vpn_tun0` would be enough.

Comment: Spot on! Please write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . Hope this will solve your requirement.

spawn bash

set dh_client $spawn_id

send "dhclient vpn_tun0\r"

expect ""